# Woocommerce - Price Dependent Shipping Cost - Is there a better way?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am looking for a free solution (Come on, Wordpress should be open source!) to have a single shipping cost option  depending on the shopping cart price. Let's say, I want to ship for free if the total cart amount is $50 and above and want to charge $4.99 if the total cart amount is less than the required amount, which is $50.

**What have I tried so far?**

Well, the best working solution that I could find is to configure Flat Rate Shipping for all products and ship free if amount is greater than X. The problem with this is the fact that both the options(Free Shipping and Flat Rate Shipping) are shown to the users when they reach the cart. I don't want that.

I just want to tell them, pay $4.99 for shipping if their cart amount is less than $50 and so on.

**Filters I have tried so far:** `woocommerce_package_rates` doesn't work. It doesn't even execute.

I think it would be great to have a solution for this, as I could not find any. This should be a basic feature of any E-commerce solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Was searching myself for a plugin like this.

It looks like I found a free plugin for this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-table-rates/stats/

Only installed it, but not yet tested it, because I do not have products in DB :P

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same option, aparently Woocommerce itself has it covered:
Everything on functions.php

**Snippets for WC 3.0+**

```
/**
 * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available.
 * Updated to support WooCommerce 2.6 Shipping Zones.
 *
 * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package.
 * @return array
 */
function my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates ) {
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'my_hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 100 );
```

**Snippets for WC 2.5**

```
/**
 * woocommerce_package_rates is a 2.1+ hook
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_when_free_is_available', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Hide shipping rates when free shipping is available
 *
 * @param array $rates Array of rates found for the package
 * @param array $package The package array/object being shipped
 * @return array of modified rates
 */
function hide_shipping_when_free_is_available( $rates, $package ) {

    // Only modify rates if free_shipping is present
    if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping'] ) ) {

        // To unset a single rate/method, do the following. This example unsets flat_rate shipping
        unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );

        // To unset all methods except for free_shipping, do the following
        $free_shipping          = $rates['free_shipping'];
        $rates                  = array();
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Source: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/

I´ve tested and works, Woocommerce cache wipe is important, otherwise keeps showing all options.

Answer (score -2):

Woocommerce has a built-in "Free Shipping" transport method which has the option to specify the minimum amount. Should be exactly your case.

Comment: I do not want to have multiple options such as.. Flat Rate Shipping and Free Shipping.. I want to have only one option which says free shipping if amount greater than x, or flat rate shipping if amount less than x.

Comment: well, you would be halfway there. If you really need to hide the other option for purchases over the desired amount, the filter you're looking for is `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`.

Comment: Sorry, got confused. The filter handling shipping seems to be `woocommerce_cart_shipping_packages`. This part seems to be more confusing than it used to be in previous versions.

Comment: or rather, modify availability directly from the excess method: `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_' . $this->id . '_is_available', $is_available, $package );` - filter would be `woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_avaible'.